# error occurred creating certificates with Let's Encrypt

Tags: node.js, lets-encrypt, amazon-lightsail

Im trying to create certificate for my AWS lightsail instance (Node.js).
I am using a domain I bought from GoDaddy.com.
I updated nameservers from my AWS lightsail instance,
Also I made static IP for my instance.
When I tried to run the following command:
`sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool --perform_public_ip_ validation 0 --perform_dns_validation 0`

I received this error:

An error occurred creating certificates with Let's Encrypt:

`````
2023/06/17 14:41:57 [INFO] [mysite.com, www.mysite.com] acme: Obtaining 
bundled SAN certificate
2023/06/17 14:41:58 [INFO] [mysite.com] AuthURL: 
https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/237341122057
2023/06/17 14:41:58 [INFO] [www.mysite.com] AuthURL: 
https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/237617502127
2023/06/17 14:41:58 [INFO] [www.mysite.com] acme: authorization already valid; 
skipping challenge
2023/06/17 14:41:58 [INFO] [mysite.com] acme: use tls-alpn-01 solver
2023/06/17 14:41:58 [INFO] [mysite.com] acme: Trying to solve TLS-ALPN-01
2023/06/17 14:42:03 [INFO] Skipping deactivating of valid auth: 
https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/237341122057
2023/06/17 14:42:03 [INFO] Deactivating auth: 
https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/237617502127
2023/06/17 14:42:03 Could not obtain certificates:
error: one or more domains had a problem:
[mysite.com] acme: error: 400 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: no valid A 
records found for mysite.com; no valid AAAA records found for mysite.com````   


Why did I receive it? where do I need to update A and AAA records?

Thanks In Advance
`````